# Delegate method not called objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates, protocols

So I am calling delegate function but some how its not getting called, I tried everything from all the other similar threads but nothing works. It looks all good but the method is still not called.  here is my code below -

So i created protocol like this - 
AuthViewController.h

```
@class AuthViewController;

@protocol AuthViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>
- (void)updateNavigation:(NSString*)pageType
                        message:(NSString*)message;
@end
```

created a property -

```
@property (nonatomic, weak)id delegate;
```

And called the function in AuthViewController.m -

```
[self.delegate updateNavigation:@"xx" message:@"xx"];
```

Then in other class -

```
AssociateViewController.h
@interface AssociateViewController : UIViewController <AuthViewControllerDelegate>
@property (nonatomic, strong)AuthViewController *vc;
@End
```

AssociateViewController.m

First set the delegate in a button action or viewWillAppear(I tried both)-

```
 self.vc = [[AuthViewController alloc] init];
    self.vc.delegate = self;
```

And the here is the method which is somehow never called :( -

```
  - (void)updateNavigation:(NSString*)pageType
                     message:(NSString*)message;
    {
        //method to do 
    }
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Are you able to call `[self.delegate updateNavigation` ? check if `self.delegate` exist

Comment: There is nothing wrong about they way you set up the delegate so I guess problem is somewhere else. Put a breakpoint to `[self.delegate updateNavigation:...]` and check that the code is reached and that `delegate` is not `nil`.

Comment: Do you display `self.vc` after creating it and setting the delegate or are you using an `AuthViewController` on the screen that you got somewhere else...like from a storyboard or xib?

Comment: @iphonic I checked, self.delegate is nil, but not sure why is it nil? I used self.vc only to setup the delegate.

Comment: I suspect your problem is that you set up the delegate for one instance of `AuthViewController` and then try to use it from a different instance.  Use the debugger or `NSLog` to examine the address of `self` at the time you call `updateNavigation` and compare it to `self.vc` when you assign the delegate.  I'm guessing that you'll see different values, therefore different objects.

Comment: Ok i tested that, it returns for self - <AuthViewController: 0x7f9780d58030> and for self.vc <AuthViewController: 0x7f978820a7e0> but how do i make sure its same?

Comment: I can't tell you exactly without knowing the structure of your program but you need to set the delegate in the object where you want to call the delegate method rather than creating some **different** object, setting the delegate, and then not using it.

Comment: I am setting delegate to self in AssociateViewController.m and the delegate method is called from AuthViewController.m which is after three another  view controllers, where many service calls are made. Could that be the issue?

Comment: I think the basic issue is `[[AuthViewController alloc] init]`.  You need to get rid of that and use a pointer to the `AuthViewController` instance that's actually part of the controller hierarchy when you make the delegate assignment.

Comment: To add to Phillip's suggestion, and assuming there's an associated VC in a storyboard, instantiating a VC programmatically involves calling `[[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:bundle:] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:];`

Comment: Try to set the property like so: @property (nonatomic, weak)id <AuthViewControllerDelegate> delegate;

Comment: Where are you originally instantiating this AuthViewController? Are you doing presentViewController: or pushViewController: somewhere with AuthViewController? Whoever does that has the reference to AuthViewController, and presumably needs to set the delegate. Otherwise, that class needs a public property of AuthViewController that another class would use to set the delegate. If it's displaying via storyboard magic you'll have to make sure you have a property linked to the AuthVC. Your problem is definitely that you're creating a new instance and setting the delegate on that instance.